# PHP Excel RATE with anually increasing payment (pmt)

Tags: php, excel, algorithm, math, finance

I am using the PHP Version of [Excels RATE function](https://exceljet.net/functions/rate-function) in order to calculate the interest rate of an annuity.

This is working out as expected.
My question now is if I can somehow work with a variable, anually increasing $pmt value.

Example:
Year 1: Payment($pmt): $1,200, anual increase 10%, term remaining: 20years
Year 2: Payment($pmt): $1,320 ($1,200 + 10%), term remaining: 19years
Year 3: Payment($pmt): $1,452 ($1,320 + 10%), term remaining: 18years
etc...

I can't use the total amount of payments and then divide by the amount of years in order to get a averaged $pmt value, since this will mess with the interest calculations of the RATE() function and produce inaccurate results

So ideally I could do something like: RATE(60,10,-1200,0,80000), where 10 is the anual increase of the 1200 payment.

```
function RATE($nper, $pmt, $pv, $fv = 0.0, $type = 0, $guess = 0.1) {
    $financial_max_iterations = 20;
    $financial_precision = 0.00000008;

    $rate = $guess;
    if (abs($rate) < $financial_precision) {
        $y = $pv * (1 + $nper * $rate) + $pmt * (1 + $rate * $type) * $nper + $fv;
    } else {
        $f = exp($nper * log(1 + $rate));
        $y = $pv * $f + $pmt * (1 / $rate + $type) * ($f - 1) + $fv;
    }
    $y0 = $pv + $pmt * $nper + $fv;
    $y1 = $pv * $f + $pmt * (1 / $rate + $type) * ($f - 1) + $fv;

    // find root by secant method
    $i  = $x0 = 0.0;
    $x1 = $rate;
    while ((abs($y0 - $y1) > $financial_precision) && ($i < $financial_max_iterations)) {
        $rate = ($y1 * $x0 - $y0 * $x1) / ($y1 - $y0);
        $x0 = $x1;
        $x1 = $rate;

        if (abs($rate) < $financial_precision) {
            $y = $pv * (1 + $nper * $rate) + $pmt * (1 + $rate * $type) * $nper + $fv;
        } else {
            $f = exp($nper * log(1 + $rate));
            $y = $pv * $f + $pmt * (1 / $rate + $type) * ($f - 1) + $fv;
        }

        $y0 = $y1;
        $y1 = $y;
        ++$i;
    }
    return $rate;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't you be better off using irr() instead of rate()?

Comment: Is the payment monthly or annual?

Comment: This code would be easier to read with more descriptive names of variables, like `$payment` instead of `$pmt`, etc. It may help other users to answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it happens, this setting of payments results in a nice
generalization  of the original formula.

With the [standard meaning](https://exceljet.net/functions/rate-function)
of the parameters, `$nper`, `$pmt`, `$pv`, `$fv`, `$type`, `guess`,
except we take `$pmt` to be an array of `$nper` numbers,
the equation that gives the rate `$rate` is:

- if `$type == 0`

```php
$pv * (1 + $rate)**$nper + // present value after $nper
  $pmt[0] * (1 + $rate)**($nper-1) + // 1st payment, after $nper-1
  $pmt[1] * (1 + $rate)**($nper-2) + // 2nd payment, after $nper-2 
  // ................................\
  $pmt[n-2] * (1 + $rate)**1 + //  payment n-1, after 1
  $pmt[n-1] + // 2nd payment, after 0
     $fv // final value
     === 0
```

- if `$type == 1`, the first payment is immediate so
  each payment gets +1 `$rate`s applied:

```php
$pv * (1 + $rate)**$nper + // present value after $nper
  $pmt[0] * (1 + $rate)**$nper + // 1st payment, after $nper
  $pmt[1] * (1 + $rate)**($nper-2) + // 2nd payment, after $nper-1 
  // ................................\
  $pmt[n-2] * (1 + $rate)**2 + //  payment n-1, after 2
  $pmt[n-1] * (1 + $rate)**1 + // 2nd payment, after 1
     $fv // final value
     === 0
```

Now, as the question sets it, the payments are
given by `$pmt[$i] = $pmt0 * (1 + $rate_pmt)**$i`,
where `$pmt0$` is the first payment and `$rate_pmt`
is the rate of payment, both given as arguments.

With this, the formulae reduce to:

```php
$pv * (1 + $rate)**$nper +
  (1 + $rate*$type)*((1+$rate)**$nper - (1+$rate_pmt)**$nper)/($rate-$rate_pmt)+
   $fv 
   === 0
```

This nice result is used in the function `RATE_VP1` below. However,
one can see that these sums are rather fragile; one may set
them off for instance, by rounding off payments. Thus, I also
opted to a more pragmatic solution, albeit less efficient, that
simply computes the sums in code, rather than use the mathematical
result. That is implemented in the function `RATE_VP`. The two
functions have the same signature and should (and do) give the
same results.

```php
/**
 * RATE_VP
 *
 * The variable payment version of excel's RATE
 *
 * @param    float    $nper       The total number of payment periods
 * @param    float    $rate_pmt   The rate by which each payment increases
 *                                wrt the previous one (percent)
 * @param    float    $pmt0       The value of the first payment
 * @param    float    $pv         The present value (see RATE)  
 * @param    float    $fv         The future value (see RATE)
 * @param    integer  $type       The number 0 or 1 and indicates 
 *                                when payments are due.
 * @param    float    $guess      Initial guess of the result
 *                                
 * @return    float
 */
function RATE_VP($nper, $rate_pmt, $pmt0, $pv, $fv = 0.0, $type = 0, $guess = 0.1) {
    // computing the sums in code
    $financial_max_iterations = 20;
    $financial_precision = 0.00000008;
    
    $pmts = array_fill(0, $nper, $pmt0);
    for($i = 1; $i < $nper; $i++){
        $pmts[$i] = $pmts[$i-1] * (1+$rate_pmt);
    }
    $y0 = $pv + array_sum($pmts) + $fv;
    
    $guess_strategy = [$guess, 2*$guess, $guess/2, 5*$guess, $guess/5, $guess];
    foreach($guess_strategy as $rate){
      $f = (abs($rate) < $financial_precision) ? 1 + $rate*$nper : exp($nper * log(1 + $rate));
      $y = $f * $pv;
      $fact = $type == 0 ? 1 : 1 + $rate;
      for($j = $nper - 1; $j >= 0; $j--){
          $y += $pmts[$j] * $fact;
          $fact *= 1 + $rate;
      }
      $y += $fv;
      $rate1 = - $y0 * $rate / ($y - $y0);
      if($rate1 > -1){
        break;
      }
    }
    
    $y1 = $y;
    
    // find root by secant method
    $i = $x0 = 0.0;
    $x1 = $rate;
    while ((abs($y0 - $y1) > $financial_precision) and ($i < $financial_max_iterations)) {
        $rate = ($y1 * $x0 - $y0 * $x1) / ($y1 - $y0);
        $x0 = $x1;
        $x1 = $rate;

        $f = abs($rate) < $financial_precision ? 1 + $rate*$nper : exp($nper * log(1 + $rate));
        $y = $f * $pv;
        $fact = $type == 0 ? 1 : 1 + $rate;
        for($j = $nper - 1; $j >= 0; $j--){
            $y += $pmts[$j] * $fact;
            $fact *= 1 + $rate;
        }
        $y += $fv;
        
        $y0 = $y1;
        $y1 = $y;
        ++$i;
    }
    if(abs($y) > $financial_precision){
      throw new ErrorException("RATE_VP diverges", 0);
    }
    return $rate;
}
```

and

```php
function RATE_VP1($nper, $rate_pmt, $pmt0, $pv, $fv = 0.0, $type = 0, $guess = 0.1) {
    // using mathematical summation
    $financial_max_iterations = 20;
    $financial_precision = 0.00000008;
    
    $f_pmt = (abs($rate_pmt) < $financial_precision) ? 1 + $rate_pmt*$nper : exp($nper * log(1 + $rate_pmt));
    if(abs($rate_pmt) < $financial_precision){
        $y0 = $pv + $pmt0 *  $nper + $fv;
    }
    else{
        $y0 = $pv + $pmt0 * ($f_pmt-1)/$rate_pmt  + $fv;
    }

    $rate = $guess;    
    $guess_strategy = [$guess, 2*$guess, $guess/2, 5*$guess, $guess/5, $guess];
    foreach($guess_strategy as $rate){
      if (abs($rate) < $financial_precision && abs($rate_pmt) < $financial_precision){
          $y = $pv * (1 + $rate*$nper) + (1 + $rate*$type)*($rate-$rate_pmt)*($nper-1) + $fv; 
      }
      else{
          $f = (abs($rate) < $financial_precision) ? 1 + $rate*$nper : exp($nper * log(1 + $rate));
          if (abs($rate - $rate_pmt) < $financial_precision){
              $y = $pv * $f + $pmt0 * (1 + $rate * $type) * $f/(1+$rate) *$nper + $fv; 
          }
          else{
              $y = $pv * $f + $pmt0 * (1 + $rate * $type) * ($f - $f_pmt)/($rate - $rate_pmt) + $fv;
          }
      }
      $rate1 = - $y0 * $rate / ($y - $y0);
      if($rate1 > -1){
        break;
      }
    }
    
    $y1 = $y;
    
    // find root by secant method
    $i  = $x0 = 0.0;
    $x1 = $rate;
    while ((abs($y0 - $y1) > $financial_precision) and ($i < $financial_max_iterations)) {
        $rate = ($y1 * $x0 - $y0 * $x1) / ($y1 - $y0);
        $x0 = $x1;
        $x1 = $rate;

        if (abs($rate) < $financial_precision && abs($rate_pmt) < $financial_precision){
            $y = $pv * (1 + $rate*$nper) + (1 + $rate*$type)*($rate-$rate_pmt)*($nper-1) + $fv; 
        }
        else{
            $f = (abs($rate) < $financial_precision) ? 1 + $rate*$nper : exp($nper * log(1 + $rate));
            $y = $pv * $f + $pmt0 * (1 + $rate * $type) * ($f - $f_pmt)/($rate - $rate_pmt) + $fv;
        }

        $y0 = $y1;
        $y1 = $y;
        ++$i;
    }
    if(abs($y) > $financial_precision){
      throw new ErrorException("RATE_VP1 diverges", 0);
    }
    return $rate;
}
```

The example in the OP:

```php
RATE_VP(20, 0.1, -1200, 80000)*100
```

or

```php
RATE_VP1(20, 0.1, -1200, 80000)*100
```

I used the same exact pattern used in the original `RATE` function,
although some improvements (e.g., to avoid code duplication) are
conceivable.

Excel's `IRR` function can be used to check the results,
here's a [google sheets version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JyILmC50JN3pSdO57xLprS-xsG_u_wLqLgpXx_EIcXs/edit?usp=sharing),
except `IRR`'s model doesn't include the `fv`-future value,
nor `type=1` - payment at the start of the period so those should have
the default zero values.

Also for verification purposes I introduced a detailed print of
the resulting calculation in this [PHP sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/99cfd01d-9d00-42a1-b0ba-7656f82b51a1)
through the function `rate_detailed`.

**IN UPDATE**: I changed the code and phpsandbox link to

- add detection of failure to find a solution, by throwing an `ErrorException`
- add a "guess strategy" a set of variations of the `$guess` parameter to avoid tricky or edge cases that lead to failure at the very first step of the iteration.
- corrected some formulas for the initial guess in `RATE_VP1`.

Comment: I wasnt able to test it until today, but this solution, explanations and references are great! Thank you so much!

Comment: I have one question here though: RATE_VP(18, 0.1, -1800, 20000)*100 my returned value is -14.879626806473114, which is correct, if running  RATE_VP(18, 0.1, -1800, 17913)*100 my returned value is 141747.2808113353 - Is there a overflow happening here on the float? And if so, is there any way around it?

Comment: What happened was that the code diverged for that particular case, an important factor being the fact the `$guess` rate was equal to the rate for payments (but also the rest of the data).  Following the `RATE` function, my code did not detect divergence. I added now such detection that throws an `ErrorException` if the solution is not OK. In such cases, one may try again with another value for `$guess`. Based on that I added what I called a "guess strategy" - trying some variations of `$guess` value to avoid "edge cases" where the first iteration is thrown to negative values.

Comment: Appreciate the Exception handling, somehow even with the $guess strategy this Exception gets thrown relativly often in my caluclation, which is problematic, I'll try to see if I can somehow circumvent this from happening

Comment: Please send me some cases where the exception is thrown, so I can check what happens -- it may be a simple issue, but if there's a deeper problem, we may try using a stronger numerical procedure than the secant method.